# Важность Gpu для разаботки под android

Tags: android, android-studio, мобильная-разработка, gpu

Насколько важна видеокарта при разработке под android? То есть важна ли она для скорости билда приложений и отзывчивости самой android studio или лучше отдать предпочтение ноутбуку с интегрированной видеокартой, но хорошим процессором, оперативкой и ssd?

Comment: Наверное хватит просто ssd, не?

Comment: главное это 12+гб оперативы, ssd получше. Ну и проц тоже помощнее. Видео карта никакой роли не играет

Comment: 8 гигов хватит оперативы

Comment: Если вы собрались брать ноутбук то можно почерпнуть инфу здесь - https://habrahabr.ru/company/alconost/blog/335298/
Для стационарных ПК та же тема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рискуя вызвать гнев сторонников чистого ruSO, приведу свои соображения.

Скорость билда функция 3-х переменных:

1. Количество ядер процессора (играет роль для распараллеливания тасков *Gradle*) - безусловный лидер процессор i7, но надо смотреть, потому что мобильные версии процессоров всегда специфические)
2. Размер оперативной памяти (чем больше тем лучше)
3. Скорость харда (SSD вне конкуренции)

Видеокарта вообще не играет роли. Если кто-то знает примеры - внимательно выслушаю.

**P.S.**  Видеокарта для девелопера важна лишь как источник относительно безболезненного секвестирования бюджета на покупку ноута, ну и к тому же - со слабой картой особо не поиграешь. Ну и в качестве совета: если денег не хватает (а их всегда не хватает) - советую обратить внимание на ноутбуки, в которых можно апгрейдить RAM - потом докупите.

**Update**

Общий паттерн выбора я бы просуммировал так (уже 3 раза проделывал для себя это упражнение):

1. Отталкиваемся от мобильности: вес + диагональ экрана
2. Видеокарту игнорим полностью
3. вес и диагональ нас сразу же ведут к ветке: есть SSD или его нет (тонкие легкие всегда идут с SSD) - емкость менее 256 gb сразу отметаем (не хватит, уже известно).
4. Далее смотрим сразу модель с процессором i7 (без вариантов)
5. Далее самая сложная ветка: ноут идет с возможностью апгрейда RAM или без - к сожалению это можно почерпнуть только из форумов, как правило, в описании ноута эта инфа отсутствует (минимум RAM 8 гб).

Хорошие из коробки модели ноутов: Dell XPS 13, Apple MacBook, Samsung 9th Series, Xiaomi Air

Comment: Модель самого процессора. Играет так же очень важную штуку.

Comment: @FORTRAN это косвенный признак. Что именно важно? Тактовая частота? Поддержка определённых технологий?

Comment: Ну тогда и количество ядер еще более косвенный признак.

Comment: @D-side количество операций в целыми числами, с дробными числами.

Comment: @FORTRAN из модели процессора вы узнаете количество ядер и по нему будете оценивать производительность (а в реальности, скорее всего, ещё из фирмы-производителя и тактовой частоты). Вот вам и "ещё более косвенный".

Comment: обновил ответ с мнением по модели процессора

Comment: @Barmaley Лидер i9 если что. Сор за придирки)) В целом ответ хороший. Поставил + Если б еще синтетическии тесты увидеть по андроиду. И наверняка дать ответ. Как дешевле всего проапгрейдить(вложиться в оперативку или ssd или в проц. ) или как вобрать, то ответу цены не было.

Comment: че то не видел ноутов с i9

Comment: @Cypher Походу пока ток десктопы.

Comment: видеокарта важна, что бы там не писал @Barmaley. Во первых, современная IDEA (на которой построена студия), любит рисовать все красиво и хочет хорошую видяху. Во вторых, если хочется запустить эмулятор, то он тоже может прилично скушать.

Comment: полностью соглашусь с @FORTRAN по поводу модели, не каждый i7 лучше i5. В первую очередь следует обратить внимание на поколение процессора и буквенную маркировку - Y->U->HQ->K.

Comment: @KoVadim видеокарта конечно важна, но лишь как источник секвестирования бюджета. Еще не видел IDE, который бы требовал специальных настроек видеокарты под него или использовал бы ресурсы GPU. По эмулятору - да есть такой аспект, в новых версиях эмуляторов можно использовать GPU, но IMHO это актуально если только отлаживать 3D или видео плеер. А в подавляющем большинстве случаев это не играет роли

Answer (score 0):

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой, эмуляторы перестали работать на GPU процессора. Стали работать на CPU. 
 Сотрудникк гугл отвечает на баг репорт:
 ***If your system doesn't have a discrete GPU, we intended this change in order to make the emulator more reliably run on Intel GPU drivers. At your own risk, you may switch back to using the Intel GPU by going to settings page, then changing the OpenGL ES renderer to "ANGLE (D3D11)", "ANGLE (D3D9)", or "Desktop native OpenGL".*** 
 Решением проблемы было через командную строку, на свой страх и риск возвращать работу эмулятора на GPU, но это не удобно каждый раз писать эти несколько команд в командной строке Виндовс. 
 Проблема выглядела таким вот образом:

```
`Your GPU driver information:

GPU #1
Make: 8086
Model: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
Device ID: 0a16
Driver version: 10.18.10.3945
GPU #2
Make: 10de
Model: NVIDIA GeForce 820M
Device ID: 1140
Driver version: 22.21.13.8476 

Some users have experienced emulator stability issues with this driver version. As a result, were selecting a compatibility renderer. Please check with your manufacturer to see if there is an updated driver available`
```

Вот [тема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121828), где было обсуждение этой проблемы 5 месяцев назад

Точно не могу сказать, но я обновил AVD перед тем как эта проблема появилась. Где то недельку назад заметил, еще одно обновление и проблема исчезла (вроде бы). Я к тому, что видеокарта имеет влиянение, но какое сказать точно не могу. По крайней мере я понял, что проблема с интегрированными видеокартами. 
   Далее по вопросу: 1) Конечно же SSD и всю систему на неё и студию. И игнорьте  темы о короткой жизни SSD. Они сейчас стоят своих денег и живучие. Второй диск жесткий можно для хранения информации. 
 2) Процессор обязательно с Технологией `Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (Intel® VT-d)`  Не просто хороший, а именно с этой технологией. Не знаю, почему про этот момент вам не упомянули в других ответах и комментариях. Может у i7 процессоров уже обязательно у всех есть эта технология.. Сомневаюсь. Это стоит проверить. У меня i5 проц и 8 гигов оперативы плюс ssd.  Надо учитывать что у меня стационар и с перегревом  проблем нет. Я могу открыть около 30 вкладов в хромбраузере, запустить студию и даже два андроид эмулятора и неудобств не замечу. После внесения изменений в код , новый запуск на эмуляторе происходит за сек 10. Т.е. нажали запустить и через сек 10, а то  и меньше виден результат в эмуляторе. Эмулятор отзывчивый как реальный телефон.
 3) третье что надо это охлаждение. Не люблю ноуты только из-за этой проблемы. Так что прочитайте о системе охлаждения, о возможности легко вытащить кулер с радиатором и почистить, заменить пасту. ИХ стали так глубо прятать за 40 винтиков, с целью чтобы при вскрытии вы обязательно что нибудь да поломали. 
 
 Подводя итог скажу: Не обязательно i7 проц, проц может быть и i5 главное технология виртуализации, без нее вам придется использовать сторонние эмуляторы и мучаться с этой проблемой. Обязательно SDD. и охлаждение. 8 гб оперативы, хорошо, но возможность добавить ее не помешает.

**UPD**

VT-d (Virtualization technology for directed I/O) — технология виртуализации ввода-вывода, созданная корпорацией Intel в дополнение к её технологии виртуализации вычислений (VT), известной под кодовым названием Vanderpool. Виртуализация ввода-вывода позволяет пробрасывать (pass-through) устройства на шине PCI (и более современных подобных шинах) в гостевую ОС, таким образом, что она может работать с ним с помощью своих штатных средств.
 Таким образом данная технология позволяет работать с эмулированными системами на такой же скорости, как будто это и есть основная операционная система, в общем отклик такой же как от реального смартфона, если речь идет об эмуляции андроид.
 У AMD есть подобная технология, но под эту технологию нет образов системы андроид для виндовс, но есть на lunix.
Если вы замечали при загрузке нового образа андроид из SKD менеджера есть вариант либо название с intel x86, такая система работает, если процессор поддерживает данную технологию (вроде должна и материнка поддерживать). Иначе вы скачиваете образ ARM. 
  Сейчас вижу что для SKD 26 и 27 образов ARM нет в SDK менеджере.
  Вообще данная технология предназначена ускорить любую эмулированную систему, а не только андроид. У меня, например, установлена программа Oracle VM VirtualBox, имея данную технологию, я из виндовс 7 запускаю виндовс 10 и Mac OS, для работы с определенными программами, которые не устанавливаются на семерку. Системы отзывчивы, работают так же шустро как родная. Есть общая папка между системами. Всё красиво, на весь экран. Есть и минусы, то образ не запустился, то еще что то. Баги они везде..что скажешь

Comment: Непонял зачем Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (Intel® VT-d) ? Для андорид эмулятора?

Comment: FORTRAN, дополнил ответ